# Azure - sharing managed image between AD tenants

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I have a managed image created on one tenant, and I would like to share it with another tenant.

The only way I found is creating a marketplace image, but before I go down that road, I'm trying to figure out if there is another way for sharing a managed image between different tenants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared Image Gallery is a service that helps you build structure and organization around your custom managed VM images.

Using a Shared Image Gallery you can share your images to different users, service principals, or AD groups within your organization. Shared images can be replicated to multiple regions, for quicker scaling of your deployments.

For further reference, you can browse:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/shared-image-galleries

But If  you want to offer it to the Azure market as a whole,  take a read here:

https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/sell#getStarted

I believe for now this is the only way.

Hope it helps.